# how to delete fill from inner strokes so the middle is transparent?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

sorry if title is weird. basically, i want to do this as shown in picture:

[image]

but illustrator won’t let me. i’ve tried several ways to delete the middle piece or make it not fill at all. i want the middle to be transparent. please help and thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw your 2 ellipses (they need to be closed paths)

Then select them both and go to Object> Compound Path> Make.

You will get the result you want.

Comment: thanks man. it worked :)